# "random" gaps in flot chart

Tags: javascript, json, flot

I found out about this bug not long ago,
but I have no idea how long he has been there.

I have many flot charts that all have gaps on 26-27 October. doesn't matter what year!
I have already checked that no data is missing, and there is not. 
I have searched all over the internet for similar problems, the only thing close to my problem had the solultion to not include flot twice, which I don't do.
Any idea's where to look for a solution? Examples:

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

---

EDIT:

I found out what the problem is, thank you for the hint.
There appear to be null values in the (js) array. 
I create this array with a JSON object. 
Its here where it goes wrong. 
When I log the JSON object I have E.G. 100 elements,
when I perfom `array = JSON.parse(json.responseText)["data"];`
and log this array I have 104 elements. These 4 elements are null values.

How did they get in there?

Comment: Can you show us your data array. This looks like there are null values.

Comment: Thanks for hint, I can't post the array though.. way to large!

Comment: see my EDIT for new question.

Comment: You need to post the JSON string from which the array is build. We are no oracles ... (yet)